# Why a query is not covered when using a range operator on documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have created the following 1000 documents:

```
for(i=0;i<1000;i++){db.doc.insert({"doc":{"k1":"v_"+i,"k2":i},"scal":i})}
```

So a document looks like this:

```
var d1 = db.doc.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ce25f8920b0be2428648e38"),
    "doc" : {
        "k1" : "v_0",
        "k2" : 0
    },
    "scal" : 0
}
```

I've created the following two indexes:

```
db.doc.createIndex({"doc":1})
db.doc.createIndex({"scal":1})
```

I wonder why the following query is not covered:

```
db.doc.explain(true).find({doc:{$gt:d1.doc}},{_id:0,doc:1})
{
    ...
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 999,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 1,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 999,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 999,
        ...
}
```

However, the same query using a scalar instead of a document is covered:

```
db.doc.explain(true).find({scal:{$gt:d1.scal}},{_id:0,scal:1})
{
    ...
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 999,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 999,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
        ...
}
```

I only get the query covered on documents, when I'm **not** using a range operator:

```
db.doc.explain(true).find({doc:d1.doc},{_id:0,doc:1})
{
    ...
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
        ...
}
```

Even `$in` would result in a covered query:

```
var dis = db.doc.distinct("doc")
db.doc.explain(true).find({doc:{$in:dis}},{_id:0,doc:1})
{
...
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1000,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 8,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1000,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
        ...
}
```

However range operators such as `$gt` seem not to be able to result in a covered query when applied to documents. Is this an expected behaviour which is documented anywhere or is it a bug?

I'm using a replSet running with mongodb v3.6 Linux 64 Bit.

Comment: `doc` itself cannot be indexed. That's your basic misunderstanding here. You can index on `"doc.k1"` for example without a problem, but indexes will not contain an "object" like that otherwise. Also MongoDB version will play a part here as prior to MongoDB 3.6 even `"doc.k1"` may not be able to use a covered query.

Comment: Actually *cannot* is a little strong wording, and rather that should be *"should not"*. The only way an index applies is with an **exact match**. So `db.doc.findOne({ "doc": { "k1": "v_1", k2": 1 } })` would match something and use the index. `db.doc.findOne({ "doc": { "k2": 1, "k1": "v_1"  } })` on the other hand matches nothing. You typically want the index on the keys with values i.e `createIndex({ "doc.k1": 1, "doc.k2": 1 })`

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn for the insights. I thought indexes on documents may work like [multikey indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/), so every key will be put in the index, but I couldn't find any documentation about how documents are indexed. So, good to hear what you've said. Thanks!